# How do i manipulate select box using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some select boxes like the following:

```
<select id="my_box1" rel="cal_10">
    <option value="A"></option>
</select>

<select id="my_box2" rel="cal_10.50">
    <option value="A"></option>
</select>

....

<select id="my_boxn">
    <option value="B"></option>
</select>
```

On changing, I want to add the related value (that is 10 and 10.50) only when the select boxes has the same option value.

For Example: if the first and second select box has option value as A, then I want to add it.

How can I do this using jQuery?

Comment: What do you mean by "add" them? Do you mean to extract the numeric value of the `rel`, and add them? Is it only for the first two select elements, or all of them that have the `my_box...` type of ID.

Comment: are you trying to do mathmatical addition or add it as in put the element to it ?

Comment: @righSaidfred Thanks,yes mathematical addition the numeric value upto nth element when all elements has the same option value

Comment: @Dinesh: What do you mean by "up to nth element"? How is the "nth" determined. Also, by "when all elements has the same option value", do you mean they have the same value selected? Or should it be irrespective of whether or not they're selected?

Comment: @RightSaidFred I tried it and got the solution.kindly look on my answer

Answer (score 1):

Well, I really can't tell exactly what you're asking, so I'll just guess.

I'm guessing that when a `select` element receives a `change` event, we should find all other selects where the selected value is the same, and sum the numeric portion of the `rel` attribute.

If so, you can do this:

```
var boxes = $('select[id^="my_box"]');

boxes.on('change', function() {

    var n = 0,
        val = this.value;
    boxes.each(function() {
             if( this.value === val ) {
                 n += +$(this).attr('rel').replace('cal_','');
             }
         });

    alert( n );
});
```

If you're using a version of jQuery older than `1.7`, then use `boxes.bind` instead of `boxes.on`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, I believe:

```
$(function() {
$('select#my_box1, select#my_box2').bind('change', function() {
if ($('select#my_box1').val() == $('select#my_box2').val())
    $('select#my_box2').append('<option value="10">10</option><option value="10.50">10.50</option>');
else $('select#my_box2').find('option[value="10"], option[value="10.50"]').remove();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried by below code,

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var totalWeight = 0;
    var post_array = [];
                var actual_val = value;
                //alert(actual_val);
                var x=0;
                $("select").each(function(index, selectedObj) {
                    current = $(this).val();

                    var combined = $(this).attr('rel');
                    if(combined!=undefined)
                    {
                        combined = combined.split("_");
                        var is_combined = combined[0];
                        var combined_pid = combined[1];

                        if(actual_val == current && is_combined == "cal"){
                            post_array[x++] =  combined_pid ;
                           totalWeight+=parseFloat(combined_pid);
                        }
                    }
                });
                alert(totalWeight);
});
```

I will get my total value in `totalWeight`